# How to add selected row to repeater datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, repeater, objectdatasource

I was googling about how to add selected row(s) to repeater.
For example, I have a DataTable here, if I want to add only the first row to a DataSource of a repeater, how can I do that?
Another case is how to add this, DataTable.Select(blu, blu, blu), to repeater?

I know I can use a temp DataTable to be copied with only selected rows and then add temp table as DataSource to repeater.

But I am wondering if there is a better or more simple way to do that.

Thanks.